# Acidity of triphenylmethane

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, resonance

The question is : Why does triphenylmethane have such a high pKa value (going up to $33$)

My reasoning suggests that the conjugate base is highly stabilized and hence triphenylmethane should be a really good $\ce{H+}$ donor, but clearly isn't.

Where am I missing out?

Comment: "conjugate base is highly stabilized" - Why? Just because of resonance with a benzene ring? I suggest looking up the pKa of *toluene* to get an idea of how much stabilisation this actually provides.

Comment: Its the triphenylmethyl cation that is very stable, not the anion

Comment: It's like 20 units less then methane - quite a lot of "stabilisation".

Comment: It **is** a very good H+ donor, as far as hydrocarbons go.

Comment: Interestingly, diphenylmethane has about the same pKa as triphenylmethane.

Comment: I guess it would be a great H+ donor if all the benzene ring were to lay on the same plane. The fact that they are all twisted one from each other makes this hypotethical very well resonance-stabilized negative charge, just quite enough stabilized.